# Flutter - Truncated hintText in TextField, with filled property

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image] without fillColor

[image] with fillColor

I have a textField and a button inside a Row, which is inside a SizedBox.

Can you tell me why is my hintText truncated when I set fillColor ? Thank you.

Here the AppBar code:

```
AppBar(
          title: const Text('test'),
          centerTitle: true,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          actions:[
            SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              child:
                <Widget>[
                   Row(children: [
                       const Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,color: greyFont,size: 32),
                                hintText: 'Search farm or customer',
                                //fillColor: Colors.white,
                                //filled: true,
                              ),
                            )
                        ),
                        Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: (){},
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  minimumSize: const Size(60, 35),
                                  maximumSize: const Size(60, 35)),
                              child:
                                const ImageIcon(
                                  AssetImage('assets/back_arrow.png'),
                                  size: 32,
                                ),
                            )
                        ),
                      ])
                )
              ] + <Widget> [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert,size: 40),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
),
```

Comment: it works fine with fill color, Can you provide some mow code snippet?

Comment: I've have updated the code, this is my appbar (I did some modifications to make it more understandable)

Comment: Can you update the snippet,?